# Android app not run and show error after update flutter

Tags: android, flutter

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/libraries/mapsplatform/secrets-gradle-plugin/secrets-gradle-plugin/1.3.0/secrets-gradle-plugin-1.3.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/libraries/mapsplatform/secrets-gradle-plugin/secrets-gradle-plugin/1.3.0/secrets-gradle-plugin-1.3.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.

Comment: Explain the steps to reproduce this issue. More info about the issue helps others identify the question and answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
flutter clean
```

And then,

```
flutter pub get
```

Make sure you have a good internet connection.

If this doesn't work,

Delete `pubspec.lock` file and run the above commands again.